# PushNotification Alert Title

Tags: iphone, alert, apple-push-notifications

By default the Alert view title in the PushNotification displays the "Bundle Display name" from info.plist.

Is is possible to change the AlertView title ?

Thanks

Comment: @Biranchi: he just asked kind of same question 2 minutes ago!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Apple always use the display name so that end users will always know which app sends a push notification, and therefore which app to turn off if they're unhappy with it.